# In the following code, when I get multiple values out of a JavaScript function, why putting [0] and [1] after calling the function?

Tags: javascript, function

**This is the code:**

```
function get size(width, height, depth) {
  var area = width * height;
  var volume = width * height * depth;
  var sizes = [area, volume];
  return sizes;
}
var areaOne = get size(3,2,3)[0];
var volumeOne = getSize(3,2,3)[1];
```

**Why putting the [0] and [1] after calling the function?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getSize` function returns an array with two elements, `area` and `volume`.

```
// areaAndVolume1 is an array, because we didn't add a [1] or similar
var areaAndVolume1 = getSize(3,2,3); 
// here we use the [0] and [1] array index operators to extract values from the array
var area1 = areaAndVolume1[0];
var volume1 = areaAndVolume1[2];
```

The `[0]` and `[1]` after the variable here (and after the function call to getSize in your example) are array index operators. The `[n]` operator returns the `nth` element of the array (starting from 0).

Using some newer JS features make structures like this a little easier to use. If you're not conerned with IE support, you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
var [area1, volume1] = getSize(3,2,3);
```